# Drupal 7 Blocks not respecting weight

Tags: css, drupal, view, drupal-7, block

We have added a block to one of our pages that contains normal content.

For this page we have ensured that the block only displays on the specific page.

In the Blocks admin control panel we have ordered the block so that it is supposed to appear below the main content block by giving it a heavier weight.

When we save and clear the cache, then reload the page the block is still at the top.

I checked the generated HTML and indeed it is putting the block first, so it's not css reordering it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there can be several reasons:

1. website is using context module which has higher priority blocks
2. weight are changed in the code somewhere (custom module)
3. look into your database and check what height those blocks have

if non of these helps, try turning off your modules one after another and check the results